# Annotating sum while still having access to foreign objects

Tags: django

Let's say that I have a simple shopping cart system with these models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # More fields...

    @property
    def featured_image(self):
        try:
            return self.productimage_set.all()[0]
        except IndexError:
            return None

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='products/')
    # More fields...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name


class Order(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    # More fields...

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    # More fields...

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Order %s: %s of %s' % (
            self.order_id,
            self.quantity,
            self.product.name,
        )
```

When a user places an order, an `OrderItem` object is created for each product they ordered, which lets me know (1) which product they purchased and (2) how many of that product they purchased.

Now, suppose I wanted to show the user which products they have ordered the most of. I'll use this data as an example:

```
Order 1:
Product A: 10

Order 2:
Product A: 10
Product B: 5

Order 3:
Product A: 10
Product B: 5
Product C: 5
```

This particular user should be shown the products in this order:

```
Product A: 30 total
Product B: 10 total
Product C: 5 total
```

This is the code that achieves this:

```
order_items_by_quantity = OrderItem.objects.values(
    'product__name',
).annotate(
    total_purchased=Sum('quantity'),
).order_by(
    '-total_purchased',
)

for order_item in order_items_by_quantity:
    print(order_item)
```

But with this approach, I can't use `order_item.product.featured_image`. Is there a way I can have both things? Namely, the quantities all summed up and ordered from most to least *and* the ability to use `order_item.product.featured_image`.

Answer (score 0):

```
order_items_by_quantity = OrderItem.objects.values(
    'product__name', 'product_id'
).annotate(
    total_purchased=Sum('quantity'),
).order_by(
    '-total_purchased',
)

for order_item in order_items_by_quantity:
    pid = order_item['product_id']
    image = ProductImage.objects.filter(product_id=pid).first()
    print(order_item, image)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to get object property after you use `values()` as the queryset returns dicts with SELECT key-values and not model objects. You can do additional query to get products with featured images and map it to your `order_items`:

```
order_items_by_quantity = OrderItem.objects.values(
    'product__name', 'product_pk'
).annotate(total_purchased=Sum('quantity')).order_by('-total_purchased')

product_image_map = {}
for product in Product.objects.prefetch_related('productimage_set'):
    product_image_map[product.pk] = product.featured_image

for order_item in order_items_by_quantity:
    order_item['featured_image'] = product_image_map[order_item['product_id']]
```

That way you ask database once for your products, not every time you iterate over `order_items_by_quantity`. Additionally you should do `prefetch_related()` on your images.